# IDifferenceBuffer error - (Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

I'm making an extension in visual studio. But have an error using IElisionBuffer and IDifferenceBuffer.
Below is my code.

```
    public ViewportAdornment1(IWpfTextView view, IProjectionBufferFactoryService projectionBufferFactory, IDifferenceBufferFactoryService differenceBufferFactory)
    {
        _projectionBufferFactory = projectionBufferFactory;
        _differenceBufferFactory = differenceBufferFactory;
        _view = view;

        NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection span = new NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection(_view.TextSnapshot, new Span(5, 10));
        _buffer = _projectionBufferFactory.CreateElisionBuffer(null, span, ElisionBufferOptions.FillInMappingMode);
        IProjectionSnapshot snapshot = _buffer.ElideSpans(span);
        IDifferenceBuffer differenceBuffer = _differenceBufferFactory.CreateDifferenceBuffer(_view.VisualSnapshot.TextBuffer, snapshot.TextBuffer);
        differenceBuffer.SnapshotDifferenceChanged += ApplySnapshotDifference;
    }

    private void ApplySnapshotDifference(object sender, SnapshotDifferenceChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        ISnapshotDifference snapshotDifference = e.After.DifferenceBuffer.CurrentSnapshotDifference;
        var diffs = snapshotDifference.LineDifferences;
        ITextEdit edit = _buffer.CreateEdit(EditOptions.DefaultMinimalChange, null, "myedit");
        foreach (var diff in diffs)
        {
            edit.Replace(diff.Left, diff.After.ToString());
        }
        edit.Apply();
    }
```

Below seems make internal exception but i don't know what's wrong.

```
        IDifferenceBuffer differenceBuffer = _differenceBufferFactory.CreateDifferenceBuffer(_view.VisualSnapshot.TextBuffer, snapshot.TextBuffer);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Differencing.IDifferenceBuffer);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

> MSDN remarks : "The differences are computed on a background thread in
>   response to various changes (text change, options changing, etc.),
>   though all of the events around differencing, like
>   SnapshotDifferenceChanged, will be raised on the thread that owns the
>   LeftBuffer and RightBuffer (generally, the UI thread)."

(I can't upload images) error popup says :

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.

P.S.
My goal is making an adornment box that is linked to some text, like error popup (but replaces text). Is there any easier way to implement this than using IElisionBuffer?